# Casual brothers

Tags: riddle

> We're a bunch of five brothers (though others exist),
>
> We have varied jobs: one of us is a chemist,
>
> Another a hunter, a zookeeper, a singer,
>
> The oldest of us is a former adventurer!
>
> We do share a goal - we're not *that* diverse:
>
> Help you find your way (if you're not scared of spiders...)

*Who are we?*

Comment: Just to be sure, is the [knowledge] tag not required for this riddle?

Comment: Not required. Confident everyone reading this knows at least some of these brothers

Comment: congrats on exactly 2000 rep!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will now delete all my questions and answers to stay there forever

Comment: @Soltius _"Confident everyone reading this knows at least some of these brothers"_ Well, now I'm mad! Let me ruin your "exactly 2000 rep" celebration with my upvote then.

Comment: Would you like to clarify whether "a hunter, a zookeeper, a singer" describes _three_ of the brothers or just one? (Of course the answer might be that you wouldn't like to clarify!)

Comment: I can clarify that each of these jobs describes one brother each

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These bros may be

> web browsers - fits with others exist, sharing a goal, and finding your way if not afraid of spiders.

Casually employing the descriptions:

> Chrome - to cover with the element chromium, so perhaps a chemist.
>  Safari - a hunter may be employed on this.
>  Firefox - another name for the red panda, an endangered species, though common in zoos.
>  Opera - a singer will be employed here.
>  Internet explorer - explorer being the adventurer (maybe being edged out by MS, so ex).

Comment: That last one may also refer to an incarnation of this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326023/165320

Comment: rot13(fcvqre nf va fcvqre **jrof**)

Comment: Good job! The "casual" part was actually refering to the defenition of "browsing" which can mean searching in a idle way, but other than that, perfect !